# Java signing an XML File - Determine Tag where signature will be put in

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

Situation: Two systems send and receive files from each other. I wrote a Java application to sign and validate signatures over an file.

So my application got an signed XML from the TPS and tries to check it against an XSD Schema. 
My problem is, the signature inside the XML arrives like this:
...

But I want to sign XML in a way, that I can determine the tag by myself: 
...

Could somebody give me any clue to solve this problem?

Comment: atm: "<Signature><SignedInfo>...</Signature></SignedInfo>"


WHAT I WANT --> "<xyz:Signature><SignedInfo>...</Signature></xyz:SignedInfo>"

Comment: found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300486/how-to-add-namespace-while-signing-xml-file-using-javax-xml-crypto-dsig